# Could a TrainedModel be re-used in Google Prediction?

Tags: google-prediction

I am using Google Prediction v1.5 (Java client) with the "PredictionSample.java" sample program.

In "PredictionSample.java", I specify "MODEL_ID" as "mymodel", "APPLICATION_NAME" as "MyApplication" and train the model using "language_id.txt" stored in my Google Cloud Storage bucket. The sample program runs OK and performs several predictions using some input features.

However, I wonder where is the "mymodel" TrainedModel stored. Is it stored under my "Google APIs console" project ? (but it seems that I could not find "mymodel" in my "Google APIs console" project)

In the FAQ of the Google Prediction API, it says that "You cannot currently download your model.". It seems that the TrainedModel ("mymodel") is stored somewhere in the Google Prediction server. I wonder where exactly is the actual store location, and how could I re-use this TrainedModel to perform predictions using the Google Prediction v1.5 Java client (i.e. without re-training the model in future predictions).

Does anyone have ideas on this. Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The models are stored in Google's Cloud and can't be downloaded.

Models trained in Prediction API 1.5 and earlier are associated with the user that created them - and cannot be shared with other users.

If you use Prediction API 1.6 (released earlier this month), models are now associated with a project (similar to Google Cloud Storage, BigQuery, Google Compute Engine and other Google Cloud Platform products) which means that the same model can now be shared amongst all members of the project team.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find out that I do not need to re-train the TrainedModel for future predictions. I just delete the

```
train(prediction);
```

statement in "PredictionSample.java" and I could still perform predictions from the "mymodel" TrainedModel.

The TrainedModel is in fact stored somewhere in the Google Prediction server. I could "list" it through the "APIs Explorer for Prediction API". I could perform predictions from it once it is trained/inserted. But I could not download it for my use.